# CentOS Navegar entre directorios

Tags: linux, docker, centos, contenedores, wsl

Me encuentro iniciando con CentOS y luego de un par de problemas de instalación por fin a quedado wsl, podman, skopeo, y buildah.

Me encontraba trabajando en docker y generaba una imagen con un dockerfile para subirlo en mi instalación pero por una "situación" me e tenido que mudar de contenedor y ahora mi intención es ubicarme en mi carpeta de proyecto.

1. mi primera duda es como moverme entre carpetas desde mi centOS que me localiza en root al iniciar

la documentación me indica que me puedo ubicar como en terminal con cd  y obtener una lista de carpetas contenidas con "ls" y localizar en que carpeta me encuentro con el comando "pwd"
pwd me dice que me encuentro en "root"
"ls" me muestra una lista :
bin  boot  dev  etc  init  ....

pero no me deja navegar entre estas al ejecutar "cd dev" por ejemplo y me gustaría poder localizar una carpeta en mi directorio para poder luego ejecutar mi dockerfile

2 aun no llego a este problema, pero muchos me comentan que docker y podman son muy similares. y me gustaria saber si es posible ejecutar tal cual mi dockerfile (es lo mas básico del ejemplo de un tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas no se si aun te sirva pero yo tenia un problema algo similar y a la hora de conectarme por terminal y queres naverga no me dejaba pero si usas `cd ..` te va a colocar en el directorio raiz / y ahi puedes navergar libremente con los comandos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).